# Is there a word for when something looks correct when wrong?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for when something looks (in the prototypical, ie visual, sense) correct when wrong? For instance in art, drawing something that technically would be wrong in reality, but drawing it correctly actually looks wrong and drawing it wrong looks correct.

I used to perform magic and I thought there was a term for this.

Comment: You mean an _illusion_?

Comment: We call those optical illusions. By the way, there is never anything wrong in reality. :)

Comment: 'Drawing something correctly' can mean a lot of things, and 'correct' is subjective in that context. Are you talking about perspective, colour, shading, ..?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a [***paradox illusion***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_illusion) If this is obvious skip to the bottom.

***illusion***

> An instance of a wrong or misinterpreted perception of a sensory experience.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/illusion)

From that we have the broadly-termed  ***optical* illusion**...

> An *optical illusion* (also called a visual illusion) is an illusion caused by the visual system and characterized by a visual percept that arguably appears to differ from reality. Illusions come in a wide variety; their categorization is difficult because the underlying cause is often not clear, but a classification proposed by Richard Gregory is useful as an orientation. According to that, there are three main classes: physical, physiological, and cognitive illusions, and in each class there are four kinds: Ambiguities, distortions, paradoxes, and fiction

The most common examples I can think of include Escher drawings

[image]

...which are  sometimes called a ***paradox* illusion.**

> > ***Paradox illusions*** (or impossible object illusions) are generated by objects that are paradoxical or impossible, such as the Penrose triangle or impossible staircase seen, for example, in M. C. Escher's Ascending and Descending and Waterfall.

Other examples of optical illusions from the 1960s abound...

[image]

A complete list of the classes of illusions can be found at [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optical_illusions)

[Emphasis in citations is mine]

Comment: I'm starting to doubt my own answer so if you guys wanna DV I won't mind. That, or help me edit.

Comment: optical illusion, sure.

Answer (score 2):

This is the concept behind *optical balance* or *compositional balance*, which is part of the Gestalt theory that a design needs to "feel right" as a whole, rather than simply adhering to geometric definitions that may be quantitatively "correct" but look wrong.

[Semih Yılmaz, in an article at Muzli ... Basics of Optical Balance in Interface Design](https://medium.muz.li/basics-of-optical-balance-in-interface-design-ui-4037c033cca2) shows some great examples of designs that simply look better when the quantitative rules are ignored. Examples include making shapes different sizes so that they *appear* to be the same size, darkening colors on text so that it *appears* to be the same color as an adjacent shape, or misaligning text so that it *appears* properly aligned. Subtleties in the human visual system can cause us to see differences where there actually are none, so sometimes a design will purposefully make things "wrong" so that they appear to be "right".

Comment: From the first para of your linked text " This is called an **optical illusion**. **Optical illusion** also applies to design."

Comment: @Cascabel Very true, but perhaps worth noting that an optical illusion can operate in both directions - it can make something wrong look right, or make something right look wrong.

Comment: In that case, this Q becomes over-broad, or possibly needing clarification.  Many artists of the  _Renaissance_. and  Pre-,  not to mention Greek and Egyptian,    used to _correct_ "imperfections" of their clients in portraits and statuary to account for deformities and genetic defects. The objective was to present  an idealized  image which conformed to  cultural concepts of beauty. On the other hand, others showed all the warts on the nose. That said, your post seems to be based also on "_correcting_" the illusion, and so not an explanation.

Comment: Lining things up  by apparent size and correcting for color addition and subtraction have been within the domain of graphic artists for many years.

Answer (score 0):

For some kinds of hyperrealistic depictions of depth the French term "trompe-l'oeil", literally "deceive-the-eye", is employed.  This is predominantly an art term and usually applied to art that pretends to break out of the frame or otherwise into the third dimension.

Answer (score -1):

specious is the word you may seek.  apparently good or right but lacking real merit, superficially pleasing or plausible etc.

Comment: Hi Michiel, when you copy verbatim from a website (i.c. Dictionary.com) you must cite your source! And if you are to do so, please also note the second definition, since it is very appropriate here.